# SQL query where clause for reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have this table with the following data:

```
Service_ID  Cust_ID  Service_Date   Next_Service_Date
-----------------------------------------------------
1            15      2016-01-1      2016-01-31
2            21      2016-01-1      2016-01-31
3            15      2016-01-31     2016-03-1
```

I need a condition to check if `Next_Service_Date` is found in `Service_Date` for each customer not the whole table.

For example customer with id = 15 and `Service_ID = 3`, you can see `Service_Date` was made on 2016-01-31

Same as the `Next_Service_Date` with `Service_ID = 1`

So output of the query should be

```
Service_ID  Cust_ID  Service_Date   Next_Service_Date
------------------------------------------------------
2            21      2016-01-1      2016-01-31
```

I hope I made everything clear.

Note why I want to show record # 2 because that customer has no records in `Service_Date` that matches the date in `Next_Service_Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited -- I think I understand your question now -- you want to find all records that should have a next service date scheduled but do not?  If so, a combination semi-join and anti-join would do it.

If I'm off the mark, please let me know where I misunderstood.

```
select
  t1.*
from
  MyTable t1
where exists (
  select null
  from MyTable t2
  where
    t1.Next_Service_Date = t2.Service_Date
)
and not exists (
  select null
  from MyTable t2
  where
    t1.Cust_Id = t2.Cust_Id and
    t1.Next_Service_Date = t2.Service_Date
)
```

Comment: thanks but the query dose not give the requested out put it give the first record

Comment: You're right -- I did a bad job of reading the question.  Can you clarify why you want record #2 to show up?  I re-read your question, and what I thought I understood I suddenly do not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `not exists`:

```
select bt.*
from belowtable bt
where not exists (select 1
                  from belowtable bt2
                  where bt2.cust_id = bt.cust_id and
                        (bt2.next_service_date = bt.service_date or
                         bt2.service_date = bt.next_serice_date
                        )
                 );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer yes i want Next_Service_Date not exists in service_date for each customer but the query you provided dose not apply that it gets first and second record

Comment: @Ayman . . . That is easily remedied.  I misread the dates in the first and last rows.